# python installation - new packages generically fail

Tags: python, pip

I think there's something funky with my python distro (3.6.5) on win10. This is for my Windows Linux Subsystem. (For those who haven't used it, basically there's a lite ubuntu OS running like a VM and I can use a bash terminal to access it. For more info about WLS, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). The reason I need to use WLS instad of powershell is that the package CVXPY is very difficult to install on windows (or at least some of its dependencies are)

New packages can't be permanently installed (even though installation seems to succeed) via my normal method, `python3 -m pip install matplotlib`. That call leads to a normal message  (collecting, requirement already satisfied, installing collected packages, etc). But, the call `import matplotlib` fails (both within a shell and a script).

Other packages that I've installed previously still exist, e.g. pandas. Is the installation of newpackages failing silently, or somehow being erased? The same effect is seen in every package I've tested - cx_Oracle and matplotlib. Another clue is that recently python3 referred to 3.5.2, but now it inexplicably refers to 3.6.2.
Also, the same thing happens on my python 2.7 distro - `pip install ecos` works but `import ecos` fails, plus cx_Oracle and matplotlib

Comment: What do you mean by _Windows Linux Subsystem_? Are you using git-scm?

Comment: no, I mean the bash shell that you can install after enabling developer mode

Comment: Are you able to run a python IDE / does matplotlib work within an IDE?

Comment: unfortunately I have no option like that, that I know of. launching gui applications from the shell always fails. but, i've tested the two ways I mentioned - within a shell (`python3` ...) and like a script (`python3 script.py`)

Comment: What is the location dir printed by `python3 -m pip -V` and what is printed by `python3 -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages())"`?

Comment: My suspect is that `pip` from `python3.6` installs stuff for some other python dist, presumably `python3.5`, but it's just a guess. Look what other python dists you have: `which -a python3`, then run for example `python3.5 -c "import site; print(site.getsitepackages()[0])" | xargs ls -1 | grep matplotlib`, some dist must reveal it. The packages must be installed somewhere, after all.

Comment: `python3 -m pip -V` prints `/usr/bin/python3`, and getsitepackages prints `['/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages']`. the test packages can be imported from a 3.5 shell